# Returning two queries in NodeJS in a single model. Promise { <pending> }

Tags: sql, node.js, express

I've got the following problem:

```js
exports.displayArea = (area_id) => {
  console.log(area_id);
  return client
    .query(`SELECT * FROM areas WHERE area_id = ${area_id}`)
    .then(({ rows, rowCount }) => {
      let newInfo = rows[0];
      newInfo.restaurants = client
        .query(`SELECT * FROM rated_restaurants WHERE area_id = ${area_id}`)
        .then(({ rows }) => {
          return rows;
        });
      newInfo.total_restaurants = rowCount;
      return newInfo;
    });
};
```

I'm trying to return the second query however it gives me a Promise {  }. How do I go about returning two of these?

```
{
  area_id: 2,
  area_name: 'Knutsford',
  restaurants: Promise { <pending> },
  total_restaurants: 1
}
```

It should ultimately look like this:

```
{
    area_id: 3,
    name: 'Picadilly',
    total_restaurants: 2,
    restaurants: [
      {
        restaurant_id: 12,
        area_id: 3,
        name: 'Carluccio’s',
        cuisine: 'Italian',
        website: 'http://www.carluccios.com/'
      }
    ]
}
```

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood. you ran two queries, and the end result is a Promise pending type of thing. OKI look
[image]

you do not wait for this promise to resolve

```js
newInfo.restaurants = client
        .query(`SELECT * FROM rated_restaurants WHERE area_id = ${area_id}`)
        .then(({ rows }) => {
          return rows;
        });
```

```js
exports.displayArea = (area_id) => {
  console.log(area_id);
  let newInfo
  return client
    .query(`SELECT * FROM areas WHERE area_id = ${area_id}`)
    .then(({ rows, rowCount }) => {
       newInfo = rows[0];
       newInfo.total_restaurants = rowCount;
      return client
        .query(`SELECT * FROM rated_restaurants WHERE area_id = ${area_id}`)
        .then(({ rows }) => {

            newInfo.restaurants = rows;
          return newInfo;
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: Hi Ernesto,  Thank you for the answer, however I've expanded my question as little to better define my problem.

Comment: Ohh !! I see where the problem at

Answer (score 1):

How about the following:

```
exports.displayArea = (area_id) => {
    console.log(area_id)

    var q1 = client
        .query(`SELECT * FROM areas WHERE area_id = ${area_id}`)
        .then(({ rows, rowCount }) => {
            return [rows, rowCount]
        })

    var q2 = client
        .query(`SELECT * FROM rated_restaurants WHERE area_id = ${area_id}`)
        .then(({ rows }) => {
            return rows
        })

    return Promise.all([q1, q2]).then(function ([resultQ1, resultQ2]) {
        let newInfo = resultQ1[0][0]
        newInfo.restaurants = resultQ2
        newInfo.total_restaurants = resultQ1[1]
        return newInfo
    })
}
```

Comment: This one solves my issue, many thanks! I was looking around myself and came across solutions like these when googling but thought that there must be an answer in the style I was using.  I'll go and build on this!